# Movies appearing on and off on Netflix

Tags: netflix

I was watching Solo: A Star Wars Story. I paused it and came back to it a day later, where I got the message "this movie is not available in your country". The movie had also disappeared from search results. Then, just a few hours later, it appeared again in "Continue Watching". I could watch about 30 more minutes of it, until the movie froze, the loading sign appeared and got stuck at 99%. I restarted Netflix and the movie had again disappeared from search results. What's wrong?

I'm in France and I'm using Netflix on Chrome, on MacOS 14.6.